# Unable to delete an image from the media-library in Strapi V4

Tags: heroku, strapi

I have a Strapi V4 dashboard deployed on heroku. Everything works fine, except for some images not being able to be deleted, with a Status code: 500 error.

plugins.js file below
[screenshot of error on strapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUcKQ.png)

upload: {

```
config: {
  provider: "cloudinary",
  providerOptions: {
    cloud_name: env("CLOUDINARY_NAME"),
    api_key: env("CLOUDINARY_KEY"),
    api_secret: env("CLOUDINARY_SECRET"),
  },
  actionOptions: {
    upload: {},
    delete: {},
  },
},
```

},

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to comment out config of cloudinary in plugins.js

Answer (score 0):

That is not really SOLVING THE ISSUE:
Ok, after deactivating the cloudinary plugin the images in strapi “Media Library” can be deleted. But the same issue happens again when activating the cloudinary plugin.